# python efficient replacement of strings in nested array

Tags: python, arrays, string, nested, text-files

I have a txt file with thousands of lines as strings.
Each line start in the format of '#integer' so for example '#100'.

I read the txt file sequentially (line #1, #2, #3..) and get a specific array that I want, where the array is a collection of the line numbers and other lines connected to those lines:

The array is in the form of:

```
[ ['#355', '#354', '#357', '#356'], ['#10043', '#10047', '#10045'], ['#1221', '#1220', '#1223', '#1222', '#1224'], [...] ]
```

It can contain hundreds of numbers.
(this is because I have an array of numbers and further 'children' that are associated with them added to each sub-array.)

I have read my txt file before the below function, meaning that first I read my txt file, extract the numbers, and then pass that as an array to the `extended_Strings` function, which **replaces each number with the actual string for that number line from the txt file**.

```
def extended_strings(matrix,base_txt):
  string_matrix = matrix #new matrix to contain our future strings
  for numset in string_matrix:
    for num in numset:
      for line in base_txt:
        results = re.findall(r'^#\d+', line) #find the line # at start of string
        if len(results) > 0  and results[0] == num: #if we have a # line that matches our # in the numset
          index = numset.index(num) #find index of line # in the numset
          numset[index] = line #if we match line #'s, we replace the line # with the actual string from the txt

  return string_matrix
```

I am trying to make this process shorter and more efficient, for example I have 150,000 strings in the txt, there are millions of times where the txt file is scanned with the line `for line in base_txt`.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Could you elaborate on your post?

Does each line in your text file start with a number (an integer)?
If so, are the lines sorted by these numbers?
Have you read your text file, before you get to the function "extended_strings"?

Please give an example of your matrix "[ [ [],[],... ],[ [],[],... ],[ [],[],... ]... ] (level 1)".
As far as I understand it, this is a list of "numsets" (level 2).
The next-inner lists "num" (level 3) look like lists of nums.
On the other hand your function seems to handle "num" as a single number, not as a list.

Comment: Werner Wenzel - i've edited my post to match your questions. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the help Werner Wenzel,
I've found the solution that works for me and would like to share it here:

```
import re

def file_to_dict(file_name):
    file_dict = {}
    with open(file_name) as f:
        for line in f:
            stg = re.findall("(.+)",line)
            stgNum = re.findall("#\d{1,10}",line)
            file_dict[stgNum[0]] = stg[0]
    return file_dict

def extended_strings(matrix, file_dict):
    string_matrix = []
    for numset in matrix:
        new_numset = []
        for num in numset:
            new_numset.append(file_dict[num])
        string_matrix.append(new_numset)
    return string_matrix


matrix = [['#1010', '#35', '#2', '#145', '#8888'], ['#30', '#2'], ['#65422', '#1', '#13331', '#77', '#101', '#8888']]

file_dict = file_to_dict('text.txt')
string_matrix = extended_strings(matrix, file_dict)
for list_ in string_matrix:
    for line in list_:
        print line

print "done"
```

Answer (score 1):

I didn't do any metering. But I'm confident that this could help.
On the other hand, there is still room for lots of improvements.

text.txt:

```
#1 This is line #00001
#2 This is line #00002
#30 This is line #00030
#35 This is line #00035
#77 This is line #00077
#101 This is line #00101
#145 This is line #00145
#1010 This is line #01010
#8888 This is line #08888
#13331 This is line #13331
#65422 This is line #65422
```

code:

```
import re

# reo = re.compile(r'^(#\d+)\s+(.*)\n$')           # exclude line numbers in "string_matrix"
reo = re.compile(r'^((#\d+)\s+.*)\n$')             # include line numbers in "string_matrix"

def file_to_dict(file_name):
    file_dict = {}
    with open(file_name) as f:
        for line in f:
            mo = reo.fullmatch(line)
            # file_dict[mo.group(1)] = mo.group(2) # exclude line numbers in "string_matrix"
            file_dict[mo.group(2)] = mo.group(1)   # include line numbers in "string_matrix"
    return file_dict

def extended_strings(matrix, file_dict):
    string_matrix = []
    for numset in matrix:
        new_numset = []
        for num in numset:
            new_numset.append(file_dict[num])
        string_matrix.append(new_numset)
    return string_matrix


matrix = [['#1010', '#35', '#2', '#145', '#8888'], ['#30', '#2'], ['#65422', '#1', '#13331', '#77', '#101', '#8888']]

file_dict = file_to_dict('text.txt')
string_matrix = extended_strings(matrix, file_dict)
for list_ in string_matrix:
    for line in list_:
        print(line)
    print()
```

Comment: Thanks Werner Wenzel, I'm trying to understand what you did there but I can't fully. I looked in https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html to understand your code. There is no fullmatch() method there... when I ran your code it said that there is no attribute 'fullmatch'... can you explain about that?
I also don't understand what `file_dict[mo.group(2)] = mo.group(1)` does, despite your commenting.

Comment: @ Yafim Simanovsky: You seem to still be using Python 2. "fullmatch" is a new attribute as of Python 3.4. You might try to just replace "fullmatch" by "match". (Should work, didn't try.) "mo" is a regex match object. "mo.group(2)" contains the line number, "mo.group(1)" the whole line. The said expression creates an entry in the dictionary "file_dict" where the line number is the key to the value "whole line".

Comment: Thanks. Changing it to `match` is correct, but I still get a `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'`, are there any more differences between python 2 and 3.4 that I need to change in your opinion?

Comment: @ Yafim Simanovsky: Indeed, this could be a Python 2 / Python 3 incompatibility, possibly the different string concept. You can try converting the strings in "text.txt" by prepending "u" for Unicode and adding the "UNICODE" flag after the regular expressions. Furthermore, Python 2 doesn't use parentheses after "print". Apart from these hints I can't help you. I'm using Python 3 exclusively. Good luck!